# iOS6 safari keyboard closes when javascript changes focus to another input

Tags: safari, ios6, keyboard, focus, contenteditable

Currently I am working on a web app for mobile devices where I am using javascript events to move the focus from one contenteditable div to another. On most mobile devices, everything is fine and the keyboard does not hide. I have tested this on android firefox and chrome, and on iOS5 and iOS6 safari. On iOS6 safari I have found that moving focus from one div to another will close the keyboard and not change focus, instead of keeping the keyboard displayed like on all other browsers.

For example, if I have

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="1">Stuff</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="2">Things</div>
```

and

```
$("#1").on("keydown", function() {
  $("#2").focus();
});
$("#2").on("keydown", function() {
  $("#1").focus();
});
```

then I would expect to alternately be typing characters in each div, which is what happens on most mobile browsers except for iOS6 safari.

You can find a simplified example at a JSfiddle I made at http://jsfiddle.net/8jj56/2/

How can I get the same kind of keyboard behavior for iOS6?